# Quarkus native and org.kohsuke:github-api - unresolved method during parsing - @WithBridgeMethods annotated method

Tags: native, github-api, quarkus

Quarkus native and org.kohsuke:github-api - unresolved method during parsing - `@WithBridgeMethods` annotated method

This is followup to [Quarkus native and org.kohsuke:github-api - Failed to deserialize exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611441/quarkus-native-and-org-kohsukegithub-api-failed-to-deserialize-exception) question, I'm using https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/9182 patch to overcome register for reflection challenge with `GHRepository.GHRepoPermission.class` which is private inner class.

I had to add `GHLicense.class` to `@RegisterForReflection` and now my sample app fails during native compilation saying: Discovered unresolved method

```
[getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:42440]     analysis:  60,222.05 ms,  6.04 GB
Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: org.kohsuke.github.GHLicense.urlToString(java.net.URL, java.lang.Class). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
Detailed message:
Trace:
    at parsing org.kohsuke.github.GHLicense.getUrl(GHLicense.java)
Call path from entry point to org.kohsuke.github.GHLicense.getUrl():
    at org.kohsuke.github.GHLicense.getUrl(GHLicense.java)
    at com.oracle.svm.reflect.GHObject_getUrl_d595a42af79d3a07fda24477277adddcaeacd46d_608.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke(ContextParameterInjector.java:122)
```

https://github.com/hub4j/github-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github/GHLicense.java#L84 getUrl() method uses `@WithBridgeMethods` annotation

```java
    @WithBridgeMethods(value = String.class, adapterMethod = "urlToString")
    public URL getUrl() {
        return GitHubClient.parseURL(url);
    }
```

Any tips for workarounds? Or this is purely GraalVM thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely a GraalVM issue and to workaround it the only way (I know of other than changing the code in the actual libraty) is to create an Quarkus extension which would substitute the offending pieces of the library.

**UPDATE**

[This](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-github-api) Quarkus extension essentially makes the library work properly in native mode and is the basis of the [Quarkus Bot](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-github-bot) application which is used on the Quarkus GitHub repository for various tasks.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. github-api artifact is full of surprises.