# How can I solve "Discovered unresolved type during parsing" when building a native image?

Tags: quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I'm using Quarkus 3.0.0.Alpha3 and I have a dependency to `sh.ory.kratos:kratos-client:0.11.0`. When I try to build a native image I get:

```
com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: sh.ory.kratos.model.UiNodeAttributes$1. This error is reported at image build time because class sh.ory.kratos.model.UiNodeAttributes is registered for linking at image build time by command line
```

I assume that the offending code is this:

```java
static {
  schemas.put("UiNodeAnchorAttributes", new GenericType<UiNodeAnchorAttributes>() {
});
```

In e. g. [Quarkus native and org.kohsuke:github-api - unresolved method during parsing - @WithBridgeMethods annotated method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61693823/quarkus-native-and-org-kohsukegithub-api-unresolved-method-during-parsing) it's recommended to "create a Quarkus extension which would substitute the offending pieces of the library."

However, (ignoring that I don't exactly understand what that means) I doubt it would work in this case since the missing class seems to be an anonymous inner class (hence the `$1`).

Can someone enlighten me? Is there anything I can do?